# How can I restart my code to as for the first input if the divisor does not divide evenly? Also any pointers on the code to go further?

Tags: java, loops

Would I make all the code one big loop? If so how do I do that? I read that I could label the beginning as a loop and use the continue key word at the bottom?
Also could anybody tell me why when i run the code and input 2 integers (i.e. 3 and 9) and the divisor as 3 it returns: 33456678

```
package loop;

import java.util.*;

public class MinilabLoopLogic
{
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
            int number1;
            int number2;
            int divisor;


        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  //you do it!



                System.out.print("Please enter 2 integers (separated by spaces): ");
                number1 = kb.nextInt();
                number2 = kb.nextInt();

                if (number1 < number2)  {      

        System.out.println("\n\nThis program will generate numbers BETWEEN "
                + number1 + " " +  number2);
                }



                else {
                    System.out.println("\n\nThis program will generate numbers BETWEEN " 
                           + number2 + " " + number1);
                        }

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the integer your output should be divisible by: ");
                divisor = kb.nextInt();

                if (number1 < number2){
                   for (int i = number1 + 1; i < number2; i++ ){
                      System.out.print(i);
                      if (i % divisor == 0){
                        System.out.print(i);

                      }
                       else 

                          }


                }
```

Comment: Hint: the output is really several numbers sticked together, namely 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8. Do you see where it comes from? Why is 3 and 6 twice in the list?

Comment: I actually figured that part out. I had two system.print.out statements at the bottom. I just need to figure out how to restart to the first input question @Henry

Comment: Yes, to process more than one input you would use a big loop. You have to figure out the logic when and how to stop the loop.

Comment: I really can't figure out how to loop the whole program :( can anybody help me with the logic?